# How do I use template parameters with "if" and "switch" statements?

Tags: c++, if-statement, templates, types, type-conversion

I am currently writing a game engine in C++ with Vulkan and right now I am working on boiling down my spaghetti code into something more intuitive. As part of this process, I generalized a descriptor `struct` to create several components needed by the engine, and the `struct` is inherited by several objects with different types.

This is not a problem between my `SSBO` and `UBO` objects because they both have a member variable of the `VkDescriptorBufferInfo` type. However, my `Texture` object differs in that the member variable is of the `VkDescriptorImageInfo` type.

These two types are used by the `VkWriteDescriptorSet` object, whose definition in the "vulkan_core.h" header is:

```
typedef struct VkWriteDescriptorSet {
    VkStructureType                  sType;
    const void*                      pNext;
    VkDescriptorSet                  dstSet;
    uint32_t                         dstBinding;
    uint32_t                         dstArrayElement;
    uint32_t                         descriptorCount;
    VkDescriptorType                 descriptorType;
    const VkDescriptorImageInfo*     pImageInfo;   //to be provided by my Texture objects
    const VkDescriptorBufferInfo*    pBufferInfo;  //to be provided by my UBO/SSBO objects
    const VkBufferView*              pTexelBufferView;
} VkWriteDescriptorSet;
```

My attempt at generalizing the creation of the `VkWriteDescriptorSet` object is as follows:

```
template <typename T>
inline VkWriteDescriptorSet writeSet(const std::vector<T>& bufferInfo, std::array<size_t,2> dst) {
    VkWriteDescriptorSet writeInfo { VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_WRITE_DESCRIPTOR_SET };

    /* Here I try to differentiate how the VkWriteDescriptorSet object is created */
    if (std::is_same<T, VkDescriptorImageInfo>::value) {
        writeInfo.pImageInfo = &bufferInfo[dst[1]];  //requires T == VkDescriptorImageInfo
    }
    else {
        writeInfo.pBufferInfo = &bufferInfo[dst[1]]; //requires T == VkDescriptorBufferInfo
    }

    /* Then the function fills out the rest of the object */

    return writeInfo;
}
```

The above is called within the following function:

```
void writeSets(uint32_t bindingCount) {    
    // The type of the vector below depends on the calling object (UBO/SSBO or Texture)
    std::vector</* VkDescriptorBufferInfo or VkDescriptorImageInfo */> bufferInfo(bindingCount);

    std::vector<VkWriteDescriptorSet> descriptorWrites(bindingCount);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < MAX_FRAMES_IN_FLIGHT; i++) {           
        /* loop does stuff */
        for (size_t j = 0; j < bindingCount; j++) {
            /* loop does more stuff */
            descriptorWrites[j] = writeSet(bufferInfo, { i, j }); // the generalized function is called
        }
        vkUpdateDescriptorSets(VkGPU::device, bindingCount, descriptorWrites.data(), 0, nullptr);
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, my program will not compile and returns the following error:

```
Severity: Error
Line: 27
Code: C2440
Description: '=': cannot convert from 'const _Ty *' to 'const VkDescriptorImageInfo *'
```

Which finally brings us to my question, how do I use template parameters within "if" and "switch" statements?

Edit:
One of the other methods I attempted to generalize the function was with a switch statement using the `VkDescriptorType` `enum`:

```
template <typename T>
inline VkWriteDescriptorSet writeSet(const std::vector<T>& bufferInfo, std::array<size_t,2> dst) {
    VkWriteDescriptorSet writeInfo { VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_WRITE_DESCRIPTOR_SET };

    /* Here I try to differentiate how the VkWriteDescriptorSet object is created */
    switch (type) {
    case VK_DESCRIPTOR_TYPE_COMBINED_IMAGE_SAMPLER:
        writeInfo.pImageInfo = &bufferInfo[dst[1]];  //requires T == VkDescriptorImageInfo
    default:
        writeInfo.pBufferInfo = &bufferInfo[dst[1]]; //requires T == VkDescriptorBufferInfo
    }

    /* Then the function fills out the rest of the object */

    return writeInfo;
}
```

Comment: `if` -> `if constexpr` (and requires C++17 or later)

Comment: `typedef struct` isn't needed in C++. Just make it `struct VkWriteDescriptorSet { ... };` and it'll be `typedef`ined automatically

Comment: @TedLyngmo It seems as if that is vulkan code and probably C :-)

Comment: @user17732522 smh, of course it would be that simple lol, what about if it were in a switch statement? I will edit my post with an example.

Comment: @ModernEraCaveman There is unfortunately no syntax for a `switch`. In that case either an `if constexpr`/`else` chain or the "old way" of writing and calling explicit/partial specializations of functions templates or static member functions of class templates would need to be used.

Comment: @chrysante I thought Vulcan was a C++ library. Anyway, the `typedef` is only needed if it's actually going to be compiled by a C compiler.

Comment: @TedLyngmo It is a C API and the code shown is from that library's interface header. They can't (and shouldn't) modify it. It is written to support both C and C++. There are wrapper libraries around the base C API though that provide a C++-style API.

Comment: @user17732522 Aha, I see. I thought it was OP's own definition.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### C++17

If you are using C++17, the solution is quite simple. You can turn `if` into `if constexpr`:

```cpp
VkWriteDescriptorSet writeInfo { VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_WRITE_DESCRIPTOR_SET };

if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, VkDescriptorImageInfo>) {
    writeInfo.pImageInfo = &bufferInfo[dst[1]];
}
else {
    // Optional assertion; ensures that were aren't working with some third type.
    // This also documents our type expectation.
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<T, VkDescriptorBufferInfo>);
    writeInfo.pBufferInfo = &bufferInfo[dst[1]];
}
```

Note that there is no such thing as `switch constexpr`, however, you can simply write a long chain of `if constexpr ... else if constexpr` statements to achieve the same effect.

### Pre-C++17

Prior to C++17, you could simply write two overloads:

```cpp
inline VkWriteDescriptorSet writeSet(const std::vector<VkDescriptorImageInfo>& bufferInfo,
                                     std::array<size_t,2> dst) {
    /* ... */
}

inline VkWriteDescriptorSet writeSet(const std::vector<VkDescriptorBufferInfo>& bufferInfo,
                                     std::array<size_t,2> dst) {
    /* ... */
}
```

There isn't much code duplication, so it should be fine in this case. If the functions are larger, consider solutions such as full or partial specializations of templates, just for the part that is different and depends on `T` being a specific type.